# What is the correct code to store the text that extracted from each function into variable?

Tags: jquery

I know this is not a right code, howvwer i wanna ask how can I achieve the idea behind using the right coding?

I intend to store into variable all the text inside each list item

```
var date = $('.selector1 ul li')each().text()
var time = $('.selector2 ul li')each().text()

$(selector3).html("<td>date</td><td>time</td>");
```

Yes im trying to transform it into table

Comment: Read jquery official documentation on each function http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Below code is not a complete answer but it should help. The rest depends on your logic.

```
var date;

$('li').each(function(index) {
    date = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: this will work howver i want to use the var date outside the li.each function, do you know how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to concatenate the values, this might be what you are looking for:

```
var date = $('.selector1 ul li').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(', ');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VWYej/)

Comment: i want to select all the list item so i need to use each, dont you think?

Comment: what you want then? select all items? could you modify the html part of jsfiddle so we see what markup you have?

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion I have edited jfiddle so you can see clearer hope you can help me http://jsfiddle.net/andlen_go/LuWnn/

Comment: are you trying to transform the lists into html table?

Comment: it's still not clear what you actually want, check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuWnn/1/) and try to modify it to your needs